# Simple approach to CRUD intersection table in MVC ASP.NET and EF?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I am using C#, MVC3, EF5, SQL Server 2008 R2.

I have an intersection table ie

```
Lecturer -< LecturerCourse >- Course
```

The list of Lecturers are populated.

When I add a course, it would be neat to have a list of Lecturers that I could select from, that teach the course in question. When I save the new Course record, this multiselect also should save its data back to the "LecturerCourse" table via Model Binding.

I am using EF5.

Can you recommended a simple and standard approach to solving CRUD for a join, ie "LecturerCourse", table? I have looked online, but some of the approaches seem very complicated.

Many thanks.

Comment: It's unclear to me why you want a join on `LecturerCourse` for a _new_ `Course`. The new `Course` is not in the database and nothing is there for the `LecturerCourse`. The confusion stems from what you said: _have a list of Lecturers that I could select from, that teach the course in question_. If the `Course` is newly created, how do you expect to know which `Lecturer` teaches it ?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, and I understand your confusion. Basically I would need to save the new course first, then enable the user to select and save a number of lecturers that can teach on that course. For UI simplicity I was thinking along the lines of adding a Multiselect box to the new course form, although the course would be saved first in the controller. Having a seperate page just to create the LectureCourse records would not be very eloquent from a UI perspective.

Comment: Technically, you can do both at the same time. I'll try to write something up.

Comment: You are a star, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, it's going to be a long one. To allow this to happen in "one page" (through POST, or you could use Ajax, technically), you need a combination of a Get and Post version of the method and to construct your view model correctly. Below are the classes that I will use for demonstration purposes:

```
public class NewCourse
{
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    // And your other properties
    public int[] LecturerIds { get; set; }
}

public class ViewLecturer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Name { get; set; }
}

public class NewCourseViewModel
{
    public NewCourse Course { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<ViewLecturer> Lecturers { get; set; }
}
```

`NewCourseViewModel` will be the model for the View (see below). `ViewLecturer` will give you a lighter mapping between your available `Lecturer` and the information required to Add to them.

As for the `Controller`:

```
public class CourseController : Controller, IDisposable
{
    private Lazy<YourContext> lazyContext = 
        new Lazy<YourContext>(() => new YourContext());

    private YourContext Context 
    {
        get { return lazyContext.Value; }
    }

    public ActionResult New()
    {
        var model = new NewCourseViewModel {
            Course = new NewCourse(),
            Lecturers = Context.Lecturers
                               .Select(l => new ViewLecturer { Id = l.Id, Name = l.Name })
        };

        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult New(NewCourse course)
    {
        if(ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var lecturers = course.Lecturers
                                  .Select(l => new Lecturer { Id = l.Id })
                                  .ToList();

            foreach(var lecturer in lecturers)
                Context.Lecturers.Attach(lecturer);

            var newCourse = new Course {
                Name = course.Name,
                // ... and the rest of the mapping
                Lecturer = lecturers
            };

            context.Courses.Add(newCourse);
            context.SaveChanges();
            // Could have to handle DbUpdateException if you want

            return RedirectToAction(...);
        }

        return View(new NewCourseViewModel {
            Course = course,
            Lecturers = Context.Lecturers
                               .Select(l => new ViewLecturer { Id = l.Id, Name = l.Name })
        });
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if(lazyContext.IsValueCreated)
            lazyContext.Value.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Your first `New` method will give you the entry point for your `Course` creation page. The rest of the validation and actual adding will be done through the `[HttpPost]`overload. As for your `View` (that should be in the `~/Views/Course/New.cshtml`):

```
@model NewCourseViewModel

// ... Then when you are ready to begin the form

@using(Html.BeginForm("New", "Course", FormMethod.Post))
{
    // Your List of Lecturers    
    @Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.Course.LecturerIds, 
                     new MultiSelectList(
                         Model.Lecturers, 
                         "Id", 
                         "Name", 
                         m.Course.LecturerIds ?? new int[0]
                     ))

    // Your Other Model binding
}
```

When the submit button will be pressed, the action matched will be the `New(NewCourse course)`. The names are important because of the way the `HtmlHelper`s generate their Ids. Because we are only included one property of the whole view model, it will match the parameter name `course` based on the view model's `Course` property. You will get a list of `Id`s for the Lecturers which you will be able to use to attach to the `DbContext` and add directly to the new `Course` model (Entity Framework will do the rest). In cases where there was a problem, we can get back the list of lecturers and re-use the same `NewCourse` in the view model.

Now this is example is very basic but it should give you a good starting point as to how you can structure your view model.

Comment: Wow.....!! What can I say, but a huge thank you. Very comprehensive. Thank you so much.

Comment: @SamJolly You're welcome. I've had to use something similar lately but using javascript to generate the proper Ids to be passed to the controller (where Web API was not an option). Glad it could enlighten you. ;)

Comment: Quick Question. I see you pass in "NewCourseViewModel" into the view via the new() action, but take the "NewCourse" model back via the new() post action. Is this different deliberate or a mistake?

Comment: @SamJolly It is not a mistake. The `NewCourseViewModel` encompass the class containing the information relating to a new `Course` **and** the extra-information you will need (the list of `Lecturer` currently in your database). `NewCourse` is the paramater in the `HttpPost` because the actual model you want to use is the  `NewCourse` model.

Comment: Ah I see, I think it because you are using "m.Course" in the helpers which brings the form element to the correct level? Is my thinking correct? Thanks.

Comment: @SamJolly Correct. The @model Directive associate the NewCourseViewModel to the `Model` property of the view (and the context of the HtmlHelper's lambda). Doing `m => m.Course` enters into the new course class. The property name is important as said previously.